# Оптимизация кода по времени выполнения

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.6

Есть совершенно несложная по сути задачка с таким условием:
**Дан массив a из *n* целых чисел. Напишите программу, которая найдет число, которое встречается в массиве наибольшее число раз** (взято отсюда: https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/12341/enter/).
Я недавно начал учить питон, смог придумать такое решение, которое очевидно не оптимальное, но точно должно быть верным:

```py
n=int(input())
a=[int(j) for j in input().split()]
b={}
for i in a:
    b[i]=b.get(i, 0)+1
for k, v in sorted(b.items(), reverse=True):
    if b[k]==max(b.values()):
        print(k)
        break
```

Проблема заключается в том, что на задачу также накладывается ограничение по времени (2 секунды) и памяти (256Mb). Можете ли вы подсказать, с помощью каких методов можно улучшить/оптимизировать решение?

Edit: Да, виноват, что сразу не отметил, при нескольких элементах, встречающихся одинаково часто, вывести надо наибольший

Comment: Какие есть ограничения на `n`?

Comment: Не больше 300 000

Comment: Гугл мне подсказывает (сам я python не знаю), что в питоне есть специальный тип коллекций - `Counter` и даже с методом `most_common()`. Мне кажется, оно там должно быть достаточно оптимизировано, чтобы с запасом уложиться в указанные лимиты, тем более, что 300 000 - это не так много.

Comment: да, кстати, можно ли пользоваться библиотеками и функцией `max()`?

Comment: Интерпретатор python используется в  т.н. дефолтной сборке, то есть Counter, наверно, должен быть. Функция не должна вызывать проблем точно

Comment: Мне кажется быстрее будет отсортировать массив и сразу начать бегать по нему, если элемент равен предыдущему, то увеличиваем счётчик на 1 и запоминаем число. Если следующий элемент не равен предыдущему, то записываем в максимум число из счётчика и запоминаем число, затем обнуляем счётчик и дальше смотрим. Т.е. бегаем поэлементно, сравниваем числа и запоминаем наибольшее вхождение

Comment: @Nobody да, это действительно может быть лучше, я попробую. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно еще попробовать вариант с вычислительной сложностью `O(n)`, требование по памяти `O(m)`, где `m` - число уникальных элементов и `m <= n`:

```
def my_mode(nums):
    r = {}
    max_cnt = -9999999999999999999999999999
    max_num = -9999999999999999999999999999

    for i in nums:
        r[i] = r.get(i, 0) + 1
        if r[i] > max_cnt:
            max_cnt = r[i]
            max_num = i
        elif r[i] == max_cnt:
            if i > max_num:
                max_num = i
    return max_num
```

Тесты:

```
In [156]: my_mode([2,1,2,1,3])
Out[156]: 2

In [157]: my_mode([2,1,2,1,1,3])
Out[157]: 1

In [158]: my_mode([3,2,1])
Out[158]: 3
```

Comment: Этот алгоритм не более линейный, чем тот, что используется в Counter (в среднем линейный). Но этот код однозначно медленнее, просто потому, что код Counter написан на си, и менее универсальный - работает только с числами.

Comment: @extrn, я по-моему нигде не утверждал, что этот алгоритм "самый линейный" алгоритм в мире (кстати мне нравится ваша классификация линейности алгоритмов: `более линейный`, `в среднем линейный`, etc.) :) Разумеется эта реализация будет работать медленнее, по сравнению с реализацией на `C`. Код будет работать не только с числами: `my_mode(['a','c','b','c','b'])`

Comment: просто не хотелось употреблять более витиеватые [термины](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7). На счет только чисел согласен, погорячился, смутила инициализация `max_num` числом. оно ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @extrn, а зачем вы свой ответ удалили? По-моему, многим будет интересно узнать о функции `statistics.mode()`....

Comment: ради ачивки, очевидно же :)

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [107]: nums = [random.randint(0, 10**5) for _ in range(10**6)]

In [108]: len(nums)
Out[108]: 1000000

In [109]: from collections import Counter

In [110]: c = Counter(nums)

In [111]: c.most_common(1)
Out[111]: [(40945, 27)]

In [112]: c.most_common(1)[0][0]
Out[112]: 40945

In [113]: %timeit Counter(nums).most_common(1)[0][0]
238 ms ± 38.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я постараюсь разобраться, с подключением модулей пока мало работал. Не подскажете, к какому источнику лучше всего обращаться при самостоятельном изучении: есть ли какие-то хорошие учебники или сайты?